# Display us states dropdown on view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implement a helper which contains list of US states. Please check here:

[Rails Select Drop Down for States?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400010/rails-select-drop-down-for-states)

Now I have to display the selected US state name on the view file. How can I access that?

As long as it is a drop-down it is working fine.

For example my user selected  `Maryland` ,in the database the value inserted is  `MD`.
Now,I have to display `Maryland` on the view page.

Please note I have simply created a helper named us_states in ApplicationHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be:

```
us_states.select{|v| v[1]=="WA"}.first[0]
```

Comment: v is just a param passed in the block. In this case it will be array of states ["Washington, "WA].