# Rails: Using array from model in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a static array in my User model declared like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
states = ['NYC', 'CAL', ...]
...
end
```

I know I should create a model for the states but I figured I just need the list for registration purposes. When I try to use it in a view like this:

```
= f.select(:state, options_for_select(states))
```

I get a Undefinded Method error. I tried using instance variables through the controller and that didnt work either. Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: use `STATES = ['NYC', 'CAL', ...]` in corresponding controller, instead of model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

States collection is not specific to a user, so I wouldn't have it under the `User` model. As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6400037/419017), I would add a `us_states` helper to your application, and use that in your views:

`= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states))`

Comment: Thank you this seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yep -- a helper handles it better here

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it as

```
User::STATES
```

that's assuming you upcase it from states to STATES since that's idiomatic :)

Another option is to create a class method that returns the array

```
def self.states
  ['NYC', 'CAL', etc]
end
```

Capitalizing the constant in the model and using the Model::CONSTANT syntax is probably the most common way to do this.

Comment: That made the trick thank you. Is declaring User::STATES inside the view the Rails way of doing this tho?

Comment: The model is where you want to define it IF it belongs with the model. You can also do things like have application constants in a non-model lib/ or concerns/ directory.